# Systemd-tmpfiles not working due to unsafe symlinks, not sure what that means

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I realized that sshd wasn't starting lately, and see that it has to do with missing /var/run/sshd, well I can create that directory, but as this is a tmp directory, it doesn't work next time it boots. I see the problem is  the following errors with systemd-tmpfiles.  I see other posts on this, but their problem was incorrect user/group of root, or run, which is not my problem, as they both show as root.root. What should I check?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

```
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/cache, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/cache/man, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/run/postgresql, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/log/postgresql, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/run/screen, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/run/sshd, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/run/sudo, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/run/sudo/ts, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/lib/systemd, refusing.
Nov 30 10:59:04 server systemd-tmpfiles[495]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/lib/systemd/coredump, refusing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, and it did have to do with ownership of the subdirectory. In my case /var was a symlink to /path1/path2/path3 .  And although / and /var were owned by root, /path1 wasn't so it failed.